# question about flutter Android License Status Unknown

Tags: java, android, flutter

My question about flutter and Android License Status Unknown:

why if install **latest version** of java .I find error

```
>>flutter doctor -v
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup 
      for detailed instructions.
```

and why if install **java 8** .no error

```
>> flutter doctor -v
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • All Android licenses accepted.
```

I don't know what is problem .so are you have any idea about this ?

Comment: Check this GitHub issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31116

Comment: For license try this command.
flutter doctor --android-licenses